# What are the downsides to adding a bunch of columns instead of creating a join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, filter, database-design, filtering

This is a general question about pros and cons for different data models.

I am creating a website which lists many Parks. Users can search and filter to find Parks based on criteria such as free/paid, which park system it belongs to, which region it's in, etc.

I want to add many more filters, potentially up to about 100 different filter options. Can I simply add a new column with yes/no enum to the parks table for each filter? E.g. "Camping", "Roman ruins", "Beach", "Shady", "Picnic tables", "Easy walk", etc.

I've read that best practice for adding tags would be to create a join table, but I tried this approach and have now run into problems querying the way I want, with AND relationships between all the filters. So I'm thinking of simply redoing the data model to give each tag its own column in the parks table (postgres DB).

What are the potential downsides of doing this?

(Note that all the filter options are predefined by me, users can't create new tags.)

Comment: From what I've read, it seems like I won't reach the column limit for a postgres table with 100 columns. Can you explain what you mean by a stop-the-world migration, and naive execution?

Comment: Hi Rebecca. I have a table with about 350 parameters that handles the styling of a complex PDF. And actually I thought it was the best solution to have that many columns. I couldn't see a better way to do it, but sometimes it's when problems arise that you realize what is the best solution. Regarding column limits I asked about it about Postgres : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/323154/postgres-column-limits Basically a deleted column can still count towards the maximum limit ..

Comment: Also I have to mention that my table is not to be searched per column. I like the convenience of Rails validation and the general Rails boilerplate but every record is reached through a foreign key. So a single index makes the table usable as it is (my app is small, need to check when it grows).  If your tags are designed to be search : someone cliks on "shady" from a random park record in order to retrieve other shady parks, then maybe something like elasticsearch...  may be required at some point.

Comment: Why don't you ask a question about the problems you encountered when trying to query the join table instead? I doubt they are insurmountable as this is a problem thats been done 1000s of times.

Comment: @max I posted twice already on the problems I encountered, but wasn't able to get a solution. Maybe you have a suggestion? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75350850/how-do-i-filter-using-multiple-checkboxes-for-a-single-field-as-an-and-query-no and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75370801/search-an-array-of-tags-with-ransack-on-associated-table
But I also realized that maybe the join table model isn't relevant if my users aren't defining the categories (all tags/categories will be predefined by me, though users may select one or more of them when leaving reviews), hence this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've already read about the best practice, it's because there are several scenarios where you could run into problems if you go with the 'columns' approach.

When you use columns for such cases, there would be many records in which some or many of these columns would be useless while they are just sitting in your DB taking up the space.
Also, consider the scenario wherein the data in your DB increases to a certain level which will make the searching on this table very slow.
There are other (scalability) issues as well that you'd face down the road, sometimes we realize it so late that we can't even change our approach anymore considering all the dependent changes and the amount of data we have to migrate.

Basically, from what I understand from reading your post, you are just making things complicated for future devs (including you) when you have the option to go with a simpler approach.

I would recommend using a gem like [ActsAsTaggableOn](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) or something similar which allows you to easily create tags (only when required) and fetch/filter records based on the tags you provide.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the kind of information I was looking to get here.